# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Why am i getting this error when everything is right?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, frontend

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `UserSidebar`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

This is the code that causes the error shown above:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import { Avatar, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CryptoState } from "../CryptoContext";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import { numberWithCommas } from "./Banner/Carousel";
import { AiFillDelete } from "react-icons/ai";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    width: 350,
    padding: 25,
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    fontFamily: "monospace",
  },
  profile: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: "20px",
    height: "92%",
  },
  logout: {
    height: "8%",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#EEBC1D",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  picture: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    cursor: "pointer",
    backgroundColor: "#EEBC1D",
    objectFit: "contain",
  },
  watchlist: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 15,
    paddingTop: 10,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: 12,
    overflowY: "scroll",
  },
  coin: {
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: "black",
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#EEBC1D",
    boxShadow: "0 0 3px black",
  },
});

export default function UserSidebar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    right: false,
  });
  const { user, setAlert, watchlist, tokens, symbol } = CryptoState();

  const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
    if (
      event.type === "keydown" &&
      (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
  };

  const logOut = () => {
    signOut(auth);
    setAlert({
      open: true,
      type: "success",
      message: "Logout Successfull!",
    });

    toggleDrawer();
  };

  const removeFromWatchlist = async (coin) => {
    const coinRef = doc(db, "watchlist", user.uid);
    try {
      await setDoc(
        coinRef,
        { tokens: watchlist.filter((wish) => wish !== coin?.id) },
        { merge: true }
      );

      setAlert({
        open: true,
        message: `${coin.name} Removed from the Watchlist !`,
        type: "success",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setAlert({
        open: true,
        message: error.message,
        type: "error",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {["right"].map((anchor) => (
        <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
          <Avatar
            onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}
            style={{
              height: 38,
              width: 38,
              marginLeft: 15,
              cursor: "pointer",
              backgroundColor: "#EEBC1D",
            }}
            src={user.photoURL}
            alt={user.displayName || user.email}
          />
          <Drawer
            anchor={anchor}
            open={state[anchor]}
            onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
          >
            <div className={classes.container}>
              <div className={classes.profile}>
                <Avatar
                  className={classes.picture}
                  src={user.photoURL}
                  alt={user.displayName || user.email}
                />
                <span
                  style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    fontSize: 25,
                    textAlign: "center",
                    fontWeight: "bolder",
                    wordWrap: "break-word",
                  }}
                >
                  {user.displayName || user.email}
                </span>
                <div className={classes.watchlist}>
                  <span style={{ fontSize: 15, textShadow: "0 0 5px black" }}>
                    Watchlist
                  </span>
                  {tokens.map((coin) => {
                    if (watchlist.includes(coin.id))
                      return (
                        <div key={coin.id} className={classes.coin}>
                          <span>{coin.name}</span>
                          <span style={{ display: "flex", gap: 8 }}>
                            {symbol}{" "}
                            {numberWithCommas(coin.current_price.toFixed(2))}
                            <AiFillDelete
                              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                              fontSize="16"
                              onClick={() => removeFromWatchlist(coin)}
                            />
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      );
                    else return <></>;
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                className={classes.logout}
                onClick={logOut}
              >
                Log Out
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Drawer>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have already provided keys at specific places where it was required, yet I can't find the mistake in the code.

Answer (score 3):

you have this line:

```js
else return <></>
```

so in the `else` condition you are returning `<></>` without a `key`, this should be the reason why you got the warning.

you can simply return an emty string to avoid it:

```js
else return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give unique key to all tags inside `map` builder.

In this code :

```
<div className={classes.watchlist}>
                  <span style={{ fontSize: 15, textShadow: "0 0 5px black" }}>
                    Watchlist
                  </span>
                  {tokens.map((coin) => {
                    if (watchlist.includes(coin.id))
                      return (
                        <div key={coin.id} className={classes.coin}>
                          <span>{coin.name}</span>
                          <span style={{ display: "flex", gap: 8 }}>
                            {symbol}{" "}
                            {numberWithCommas(coin.current_price.toFixed(2))}
                            <AiFillDelete
                              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                              fontSize="16"
                              onClick={() => removeFromWatchlist(coin)}
                            />
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      );
                    else return <></>;
                  })}
                </div>
```

You only give key to `<div key={coin.id} className={classes.coin}>` this tag. but not on other tags like `<span>` etc.

One solution is to give all tags a unique key.

Second and preferred solution is to export a functional component and give single tag to it.

for example :

```
function CoinCard({ coin }) {
    return <div className={classes.coin}>
        <span>{coin.name}</span>
        <span style={{ display: "flex", gap: 8 }}>
            {symbol}{" "}
            {numberWithCommas(coin.current_price.toFixed(2))}
            <AiFillDelete
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                fontSize="16"
                onClick={() => removeFromWatchlist(coin)}
            />
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

and use this CoinCard and give key -

```
<div className={classes.watchlist}>
        <span style={{ fontSize: 15, textShadow: "0 0 5px black" }}>
            Watchlist
        </span>
        {tokens.map((coin, key) => {
            if (watchlist.includes(coin.id))
                return (
                    <CoinCard coin={coin} key={key} />
                );
            else return null;
        })}
    </div>
```

to understand, read [this official docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys)

Let me know if you understand well

Comment: Its not working. The problem still persists.

Comment: you have to do same thing in all `map` builders like  : `{["right"].map((anchor) => (`.

Comment: Also: change `else return <></>` to `else return null`

Comment: If you make a custom components, remember to pass the React base props (key, children, className, etc.) to the returned component (here, the top-level `div`). In your `CoinCard `example the `key` prop is not used anywhere.